# filter an object based on properties of its values

Tags: json, filter, jq

I'm trying to use jq to filter a json block. I need to keep the full structure but filter out the "non-configurable" child json blocks.

```
{
  "properties": {
    ".properties.backup_options": {
      "type": "selector",
      "configurable": true,
      "credential": false,
      "value": "disable",
      "optional": false
    },
    ".properties.backup_options.enable.cron_schedule": {
      "type": "string",
      "configurable": true,
      "credential": false,
      "value": null,
      "optional": false
    },
    ".properties.backup_options.enable.backup_all_masters": {
      "type": "boolean",
      "configurable": true,
      "credential": false,
      "value": true,
      "optional": false
    },
    ".properties.backups": {
      "type": "selector",
      "configurable": false,
      "credential": false,
      "value": "disable",
      "optional": false
    },
    ".properties.backups.enable.endpoint_url": {
      "type": "string",
      "configurable": false,
      "credential": false,
      "value": null,
      "optional": true
    }
}
```

I've been able to filter down `cat input.json | jq '.properties[] |  select(.configurable==true)'`, however this looses the original structure.

Bonus marks to also filter out some of the fields in the sub-blocks, ie remove the credential and type lines.

So desired output is:

```
{
  "properties": {
    ".properties.backup_options": {
      "configurable": true,
      "value": "disable",
      "optional": false
    },
    ".properties.backup_options.enable.cron_schedule": {
      "configurable": true,
      "value": null,
      "optional": false
    },
    ".properties.backup_options.enable.backup_all_masters": {

      "configurable": true,
      "value": true,
      "optional": false
    }       
}
```

Do I need to nest multiple jq statements to achieve this? break it down and rebuild? Help (this has already used up too many hours trying different combinations and tutorials).

Answer (score 3):

So you're essentially taking an object and selecting properties to keep (or properties to remove).  Just select them.

We're making an update to the `properties` object so update and select (keep) the desired properties. Once filtered, map out the properties you want to keep in the result:

```
$ jq '.properties |=
with_entries(select(.value.configurable)
  | .value |= {configurable,value,optional}
)' input.json
```

Comment: I would have expected `map_values(select(.configurable))` to work, but alas, it doesn't. :/

Comment: Thank! I bow to the JQ master.  There is clearly a lot more depth I need to get into with understanding JQ...

Answer (score 2):

This filter will give you the properties with `"configurable": true`

```
 .properties |= reduce keys[] as $k (.; 
     if .[$k].configurable 
     then . 
     else delpaths([[$k]]) end
  )
```

[Try it online at jqplay.org](https://jqplay.org/s/AFsCRkNJDk)

This filter demonstrates how you can further refine the properties to subset of keys:

```
 .properties |= reduce keys[] as $k (.; 
     if   .[$k].configurable 
     then .[$k] |= {configurable,value,optional} 
     else delpaths([[$k]]) end
 )
```

Sample Output

```
{
  "properties": {
    ".properties.backup_options": {
      "configurable": true,
      "value": "disable",
      "optional": false
    },
    ".properties.backup_options.enable.cron_schedule": {
      "configurable": true,
      "value": null,
      "optional": false
    },
    ".properties.backup_options.enable.backup_all_masters": {
      "configurable": true,
      "value": true,
      "optional": false
    }
  }
}
```

[Try it online at jqplay.org](https://jqplay.org/s/DKBq6T83U2)

With a helper function such as

```
def objmap(cond;update): reduce keys[] as $k (.; 
   if .[$k]|cond then .[$k]|=update else delpaths([[$k]]) end
);
```

The filters can be written as

```
.properties |= objmap(.configurable; .)
```

and

```
.properties |= objmap(.configurable; {configurable,value,optional})
```

Comment: Thank! I bow to the JQ master.  There is clearly a lot more depth I need to get into with understanding JQ...

Comment: jq is very deep and I am but a humble student. I have found the [jq source](https://github.com/stedolan/jq/tree/master/src) helpful in learning, especially [builtin.jq](https://github.com/stedolan/jq/blob/master/src/builtin.jq).  There is also a lot of good information in the [jq cookbook](https://github.com/stedolan/jq/wiki/Cookbook) and on [rosettacode](https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Category:Jq).  They are well worth your time if you want to learn more.